# Why is the chrome extension not working--is there anything wrong with the code?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am a complete newbie to cs, but I was trying to play around with this chrome extension that attempts to change the background color of paragraphs to the color I want. Why is it not working? Also, on line 15 of my content.js, it keeps showing a parsing error: unexpected token. Also I'm using CS50 IDE.

[This is my content.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMNWy.jpg)

[This is my background.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fj2Jg.jpg)

[This is my manifest.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/822QQ.jpg)

Comment: Hello, Welcome to Stackoverflow! please post code instead of screenshots it will be easier to read for everyone. and clarify your problem.

Comment: You should see an error message in the console about `onmessage` - the correct spelling is `onMessage`. When you fix it, click the reload icon in your extension's card on `chrome://extensions` page and reload the web page tab where the content script runs.

Comment: It seems like it's still not working...

Comment: Well, "not working" is too vague. Start using devtools to quickly debug your code: when used properly it shouldn't take more than a minute. Also, use a JavaScript IDE that can check code syntax as you write it (usually via a ESLint plugin).

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that jumps out to me in that content scripts pic is the red closing bracket missing in the bottom of your code "}".  From the 3 images, that's what I see as being wrong.  Add } to the bottom of the page and run it again.